# Schwartz QFT exercise 3.2.(b); Noether current for Lorentz transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I'm reading the Schwartz's QFT book, struggling with the exercise 3.2.(b)

In the part (a), it requires the current associated with the global Lorentz transformation $x^\mu \mapsto {\Lambda^\mu}_\nu x^\nu$.

Let matrix ${L^\mu}_\nu$ be one of the three boosts or spacial rotations.

Under the Lorentz transformation $x^\mu \mapsto x^\mu + \epsilon {L^\mu}_\nu x^\nu$,

I think $\phi(x^\mu)$ transforms to $$\phi(x^\mu - \epsilon {L^\mu}_\nu x^\nu)= \phi(x^\mu) - \epsilon {L^\mu}_\nu x^\nu\partial_\mu \phi,$$

so Noether current is $$J^{\alpha} = \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\alpha \phi} \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta \epsilon} =  \frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\alpha \phi} (-{L^{\mu}}_{\nu} x^\nu \partial_\mu \phi).$$

Hope I am correct so far.

The part (b) requires to show $\partial_\alpha J^\alpha = 0$ when the equation of motion $(\partial^2 + m^2)\phi = 0$ holds.

My answer in (a) does not satisfies this.

Actually, I don't know why the divergence of $J^\alpha$ must be zero.

In the book, Noether current is proved to be conserved by the following derivation:
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&= \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon}
+ \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi} \frac{\partial \partial_\mu \phi}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&= \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon}
+ \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi} \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&= \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon}
- \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi}\right) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon}
+ \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial_\mu\phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon} \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi}
- \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi}\right) \right) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon}
+ \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial_\mu\phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon} \right) \\
&= \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial_\mu\phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \epsilon} \right) \\
&= \partial_\mu J^\mu
\end{align}

Of course, it is assumed that $\mathcal{L}$ does not change by $\epsilon$.

But in our case, the global Lorentz transform preserves $\mathcal{S} = \int\mathcal{L}$, not local $\mathcal{L}$.

I guess I'm thinking in a very wrong way.

Please give me some hints.